# Grouped ListBox and SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am new in WPF... :)

I need ListBox to display grouped items, what works well.

```
    <ListBox Width="120" Loaded="ListBox_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" >
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle />
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderThickness="0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

But in the *ListBox_SelectionChanged* SelectedIndex is still -1 and also SelectedItems collection is empty.

Here is piece of code behind:

```
        public ICollectionView Groups()
    {
        List<Groups> groups = new List<AC.Groups>();
        groups.Add(new AC.Groups { Items = Properties.Settings.Default.Worker, Name="Worker" });
        groups.Add(new AC.Groups { Items = Properties.Settings.Default.Flow, Name = "Flow" });

        ICollectionView groups = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(groups);
        groups.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));

        return groups;
    }

    private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ListBox).ItemsSource = Groups();
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex.ToString());
    }

    class Groups
    {
        public System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection Items { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: What are you doing to trigger the `SelectionChanged` event? Are you manually selecting an item with the mouse or keyboard? Or are you setting something programmatically?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you have a `ListBox` for each item (in the `ItemTemplate`)? Have you considered using the `ListBox.GroupStyle` property? See this discussion: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/wpf-sample-series-listbox-grouping-sorting-subtotals-and-collapsible-regions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BorderThickness="1" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Misplaced event handler ... :)

Comment: Great! Often the problems are easier than we can imagine :)
Mark your own post as answer if it solved the problem successfully.

Comment: Yes, now it's working as expected. Thank you for helping me :)